# PostgreSQL: Finding the total line total for each product that was sold in the largest order?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a college student who is currently taking a Database course, using PostgreSQL. There is one question that seem's to give me some trouble.

Here are two tables:

Table1-orders

Fields-id, order_date, customer_id, credit_card_number, cvv, and order_total

Table2-order_lines

Fields-id, order_id, product_id, quantity, sell_price, and line_total

Here is the question:

What was the total line_total for each product that was sold in the largest order? (largest order_total). 
Enter 0 if the product was not in the largest order. Make sure to enter both decimal places.

So far, this is the syntax I have:

```
select product_id, 
sum (line_total * (1) * quantity)
from order_lines
group by product_id;
```

I was able to output the product_id with the total sum of the line_total but I was wondering how the total line_total for each product was sold in the largest order.

Should I find the id of the largest order based on the order_total? Use a sub query to merge the the two tables to get the final answer? Using the sell_price field with the syntax I have above?

Comment: I don't think you need to multiply `line_total` by `quantity`. Total is already the product of price and quantity (and may even contain the discount).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the largest order. This is done by taking the first record ordered by `order_total DESC`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    orders
ORDER BY
        order_total DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Then you need to get all products in that largest order. Just join it with `order_lines` and select distinct product ids:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        product_id
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    orders
        ORDER BY
                order_total DESC
        LIMIT   1
        ) o
JOIN    order_lines ol
ON      ol.order_id = o.id
```

Finally, we need to join this resultset with your query, substituting the sums with zeros if the product was not in the largest order:

```
SELECT  product_id,
        CASE WHEN lo.product_id IS NULL THEN sum_line_total ELSE 0 END
FROM    (
        SELECT  product_id, SUM(line_total) sum_line_total
        FROM    order_lines
        GROUP BY
                product_id
        ) ps
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                product_id
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    orders
                ORDER BY
                        order_total DESC
                LIMIT   1
                ) o
        JOIN    order_lines ol
        ON      ol.order_id = o.i
        ) lo
USING   (product_id)
```

We could further optimize this query by not calculating sums for the products which are not in the largest order, but this would be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes much more sense.